# Finding the conditional expectation of Poisson Process, $E(N_2\mid N_1)$

Tags: conditional-expectation, poisson-process

Not quite sure how to proceed here in finding $E(N_2\mid N_1)$ where $N_t$ is a poisson process with $\lambda=1$.

Can't  use  the law  of total expectation or Bayes (since it's expectation?) Am I meant to decompose it into an integrand? i.e. $$\int \limits_{n=k}^\infty P(N_2=k\mid N_1=n)P(N_1=n)?$$

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align}
E[N_2|N_1] &= E[N_2-N_1|N_1]+E[N_1|N_1]\\
&=\lambda (2-1)+N_1
\end{align}